# wordpress custom pagination by page

Tags: php, wordpress

i show posts in category using "posts_per_page"

```
$qargs = array(

    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'order'             => 'DSC',
    'orderby'           => 'date',
    'posts_per_page'    => 12,
    'paged'             => $paged,
    'cat'               => $cat,
    'meta_query'        => array( 'relation' => 'AND', $meta )

            );
```

how to display only in first page 6 posts and on all other pages 12?

i tried so:

```
        if ($paged == 0) {

            $posts_per_page =  6;

            } else {
                $posts_per_page =  12;
            }
```

But then it did not properly counts... It is necessary that on the first page of output 6 posts and the second is started from 7 post, and so on. In my situation of course it turns out that the second page begins to count from 13 post ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `offset` for this purpose.

You can use something like this:

```
'offset' => 6,
```

for second page and a similar logic for pages onwards

[Reference](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/changing-posts_per_page-for-first-of-paginated-pages)

Comment: thank you so much. exactly what i needed.